# Validation of file input type using mootools in joomla

Tags: validation, joomla, mootools

Anybody has any idea how to validate a file input type using mootools. I want to validate for file type and the size of the file.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    document.formvalidator.setHandler('file',
        function (value) {
            if (value.length == "") {
                return false;
            }

            var parts = value.split('.');
            ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
            // check file type is valid as given in 'exts' array
            if (!(ext=='pdf' || ext=='doc' || ext=='docx')){
                return false;
                alert(ext);
            }
            var fsize = value.files[0].size;

            if(fsize>2097152)
            {
            return false;
               alert(fsize);
            }
        return true;
    });
 });
```

The first check works but the other two don't.